# How can I invoke GC using adb tools?

Tags: android, debugging, garbage-collection, dalvik

I want to test android apps' memory performance, and I want to get memory information automaticaly. I use 'adb shell dumpsys meminfo ...' to get memory infomation periodicaly.
Now, I want to observe memory leak, how can I excute gc ? Just like "Cause GC" in DDMS.
Thanks!

Comment: Another approach, if you have a rooted device: send a SIGUSR1 to the process.  You can see in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/SignalCatcher.cpp that `handleSigUsr1()` responds by causing a GC.

Answer (score 5):

From android studio, you can use Profiler tools.
Simply add your app session on the profiler and click on Memory sections. then press the Force GC button on the header (indicated with Trash icon)

[image: Profiler Force GC]

Answer (score 4):

The DDMS debugger connects to the Dalvik VM over a socket. In response to a "Cause GC" command, it sends a "HPGC" packet (ie., HeaP GC), which ends up in the `handleHPGC()` method of the `core/java/android/ddm/DdmHandleHeap.java` class.

The `handleHPGC()` method simply calls the `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` method.

I think you could use the Java Debug Wire Protocol (JDWP) to write a simple (??? - I've never done this, so it might not be all that simple) program that will attach to the debug port for the application you're testing and invoke the garbage collector using that API.

As the [Java docs say for `java.lang.Runtime.gc()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#gc%28%29):

> The method `System.gc()` is the conventional and convenient means of invoking this method.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I just view DDMS source code [GC:ddmlib](http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.android.ddmlib/ddmlib/) , wondering how sendHPGC() works. Would you tell me why handleHPGC() can response to sendHPGC()？Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking with "Would you tell me why handleHPGC() can response to sendHPGC()？".  Keep in mind that I'm by no means very knowledgeable with DDMS - I was just poking around in the source.  You might be able to modify the DDMS client source (or create a very cut down version) so that it that simply sends the "HPGC" packet to the Dalvik DDM handler (maybe add a command line option?).

Comment: @efei And from that link above (in the answer): "Calling this method **suggests** that the Java virtual machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects" which is exactly what I wrote.

Comment: I connect to device by socket, send "host:transport-usb", "jdwp:4946", and I recive the reply "OKAY". Then I build a HPGC packet, just like DDMS, send it to socket, but I cant receive any reply.

Answer (score 2):

kill -10 pid

from:https://github.com/TencentOpen/GT/blob/master/android/src/com/tencent/wstt/gt/proInfo/floatView/GTMemHelperFloatview.java

```
private void gc() {
    String pid = String.valueOf(ProcessUtils
            .getProcessPID(AUTManager.pkn.toString()));

    if (!pid.equals("-1")) {
        boolean isSucess = true;
        ProcessBuilder pb = null;

        String cmd = "kill -10 " + pid;
        pb = new ProcessBuilder("su", "-c", cmd);

        Process exec = null;

        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            exec = pb.start();

            InputStream is = exec.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((reader.readLine()) != null) {
                isSucess = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            isSucess = false;
        }
        // 至此命令算是执行成功
        if (isSucess)
        {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(5);
        }

    } else {
        Log.d("gc error", "pid not found!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definition of Cause GC in DDMS is :-

> In the Heap tab, click Cause GC to invoke garbage collection, which
>   enables the collection of heap data. When the operation completes, you
>   will see a group of object types and the memory that has been
>   allocated for each type. You can click Cause GC again to refresh the
>   data.

This is known as GC_EXPLICIT

Use Debug.dumpHprofData(String) to generate a heap dump.

> Dump "hprof" data to the specified file. This may cause a GC.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same situation, wherein I needed to ensure that GC is performed before I go looking for memory leaks for an Activity. I didn't get a direct solution or any adb command that could invoke GC.

Following workaround worked for me.

I registered a simple broadcast receiver with a custom Action inside the application I was debugging. Inside `onReceive` method I wrote `System.gc()` method. Then broadcast an intent with simple adb command `adb shell am broadcast -a INTENT_ACTION_NAME_HERE`.

I know it's very late now, still someone might find this useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
adb shell am dumpheap com.test.test /sdcard/test.hprof
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?